# Have you ever seen an install of IE 8 whose version number was still 6.0?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

I was at a local university computer lab presenting a website I work on and I discovered something that looked really unusual to me.  Their machines had Internet Explorer 8 installed, but when you check the version number (Help->About Internet Explorer) it listed the version number as 6.0.  It also gave me an "Operation Aborted" error that is supposed to be gone in IE8.  Has anyone else run across this situation?

Comment: Are you sure it was IE8? How can you tell, if Help/About is saying IE6?  You can put anything in the title bar you want, and many OEM's have done so ("Internet Explorer Mega 10 from Dell")

Comment: Looks like microsoft is going the way of nvidia now. Relabeling old models as new ones. Boo.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was IE8 because it had a "Compatibility View" button.  Also on the About page the graphic/logo said IE 8, but then the version number was 6.  I had to check it like 3 times because I couldn't believe me eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like the IE8 upgrade did not complete.  It could be the case that not all the files were copied, or some of the new DLLs were not registered.

Since you mentioned you saw this in a lab, it's also possible that the weirdness is a side effect of whatever deployment mechanism the sysadmins used--some enterprise deployment tools don't physically execute the installers on every individual machine; they just replicate the same changes to all the machines.  If some Registry entries or files were not properly replicated, this could have also left the machine in a limbo state.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of IE you could enable a debug mode where it reported itself to websites as whichever IE version you set. I remember a debug menu being enabled.

I don't think it changed the reported version in the about box.

No idea if this feature is in IE8.